# How to write a reusable builder class with a flowing interface

Tags: java

I have a couple of classes 'X' and 'Y' that extend a common abstract class 'Base'. Almost all of the configuration is in Base. As the configuration can be complex and needs to be flexible I would like to write Builder classes for X and Y that have flowing interfaces.

It occurs to me that most of the setter methods in the builders will be identical - after all the common code is in the common base class. I should therefore probably write an abstract Builder for 'base'. This would look like:

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract static class Builder {
        private int a;

        Builder setA(int a) {
           this.a = a;
           return this; 
        } 
    } 
}

public class X extends Base {
    static class Builder extends Base.Builder {
        X build() {
           // Do some stuff with the configuration
           return new X(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Class 'Y' would look a lot like 'X'

the client could *should* read

```
X x = new X.Builder().setA(1234).build();
```

But this won't work because `setA()` returns a Base.Builder, which doesn't implement `build`

I don't particularly want to overload each method in the derived builders to return the correct type. That's a lot of boilerplate code and a maintenance headache.

Is there some trick I can use with Generics to tell the abstract builder what it's derived class is?

Comment: What if you create an abstract build method in the base builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Improved Version**
The original answer (see below) did not support for the derived builder to add additional setters.

Yes, you can use Generics for this, but it needs a little twist. With the Type Parameter `T extends Builder` on the Base.Builder you allow derived Builders to specify that their type should be returned. The problem is, that `this` in the Base.Builder does not necessarily fulfill that requirement. So instead of using `this` to return in the setters, one has to pass/set the correct builder-instance to be returned using the method `setBuilder`. The derived Builder has to make sure to call `super.setBuilder(this)` at some point to make sure the Base.Builder is correctly initialized:

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder> {
        private int a;
        private T builder;

        protected void setBuilder(T builder) {
            this.builder = builder;
        }

        T setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this.builder;
        }

    }
}

public class X extends Base {
    static class Builder extends Base.Builder<Builder> {

        public Builder() {
            super.setBuilder(this);
        }

        X build() {
            // Do some stuff with the configuration
            return new X();
        }
    }

    Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Yes, you can use Generics for this. Make the builder class take a Type parameter `T extends Base`, and add an abstract method `T build()` to it:

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract static class Builder<T extends Base> {
        private int a;

        Builder<T> setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this;
        }

        abstract T build();
    }
}
```

Now, extending classes can specify their type to the Builder and only have to overwrite the build method, and optionally provide additional setters:

```
public class X extends Base {
    static class Builder extends Base.Builder<X> {
        X build() {
            // Do some stuff with the configuration
            return new X();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice - Thank you   :-)